# C1ReportViewer - File is not a valid C1MDX file

Tags: asp.net, report, componentone

I have created a report with C1Report Designer and show this report in a web form with the C1ReportViewer.
The report works fine, but if I add a chart control in the report, the error message "File is not a valid C1MDX file" appears.
If I show the preview in the report designer, I see the result without error.
How can I use a chart in my report?

Thanks 
Peter

Answer (score 0):

You need to add C1Chart.x.dll and C1.C1Report.CustomFields.x.dll (where x is .NET framework ver 2 and 4) in your application to display charts.

Thanks,
Richa